# ionic3 menu closing issue

Tags: angular, ionic3

In my app component I have 2 defined menus, menuA (containing some general categories like user data, settings, etc) and menuB. clicking Toggle menu button opens menuA from left side, then clicking any item on menuA opens menuB with proper data (passed through @input decorator) from right side. Now everything would be great as this is working if not for one issue.

When user has menuB open and taps on backdrop I would expect it to close menuB, instead menuA is being closed. Tapping background again closes menuB. All other methods of closing menus (swipe to right, tapping X) closes menuB first properly. Z-indexes seem to be fine as opening menuB puts backdrop over menuA.

Did anyone encountered simillar issue/what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you re-produce your problem in stackblitz.com?